# Space Time distance metrics

Tags: metric-spaces, mahalanobis-distance

Am working to cluster in Space-Time, and thinking of Space Time metrics as follow:

```
 Distance(X,Y) = DistanceDiff**2 + coeff * TimeDiff**2
```

Am not sure if this is a right definition for numerical usage (not the formal definition of metrics...), and especially if coeff should be proportionnal to

`DistMax**2/timeDiffMax**2`

ie Normalized the Space Time.

Comment: What do this have to do with the Mahalonobis distance?

Comment: Isnt Maha. distance the difference of vectors ?

Comment: Well, kind of, but the Mahalonobis distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) is related to statistics. So the question is if/what this has anything to do with Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: Numerical computation of Mahalonobis isn't part of Mahalonobis statistics ?  (numerical computation is also part of mathematics...).

Comment: Well, that's a relation, but I thought there ought to have more with Maha than that. For one you need a covariance matrix. Anyway you're not guaranteed that DistMax**2/timeDiffMax**2 being the correct coefficient for TimeDiff**2 anyway.

Comment: Hence, my question.....

Answer (score 0):

I dig into this and propose a tentative answer (although not perfect, outline the major idea).

if the space_time points represent some objects, space_time are constraints by the velocity v of the objects, if one can take v_avg (average of all velocity for all pt, at all time), one can normalize the space_time accordingly.

It supposes that objects have similar velocity (same magnitude....)